# Solving $ z = \frac{w(i-1)}{i(w-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So this might be very easy but I can't seem to think properly right now,

I'm trying to solve for $w$.

I have $$ z = \frac{w(i-1)}{i(w-1)}$$

where $i$ is an imaginary number.

What would $w$ be?

Comment: Did you try anything ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I have found out that the equation that I've obtained for $w$ and $z$ came from a mistake from me in reading the question.  I've corrected the mistake and was about to solve for $w$ now.  We can move on from this question now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite the equation as:
$$z \cdot i(w-1)=w(i-1)$$
i.e
$$w\left((i-1)-iz\right)=-iz$$